# JUL logging - instance prefix on message

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I would like my logger to prefix a text string on each message, because I need to identify which *instance* of a class has logged the message. How can I accomplish this?

I don't want to have to remember to add the prefix on each logging method call, so I'm looking for a solution which is more like a drop-in.  Naturally the logger itself can no longer be static as is otherwise the normal case.

I've investigated use of `Fomatter`s and `Handler`s but haven't been able to crack the nut for this particular use case. JUL is pretty much designed for class-level loggers, not instance-level loggers. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Would like to stay with JUL.

Comment: You can initialize an instance-based Logger object using the instance name instead of class name, and then include the logger name in the output.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException. Right. But I was looking for a solution that would include the prefix in `message` text. I cannot know what Formatter the user would want to use and he may choose to not log the logger name (in contrast *nobody* will ever create a Formatter which omits the message text).

Answer (score 1):

> I've investigated use of Fomatters and Handlers but haven't been able to crack the nut for this particular use case. JUL is pretty much designed for class-level loggers, not instance-level loggers. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

There are only two formatters included with JUL.  The [XMLFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/XMLFormatter.html) includes the logger name. The [SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) includes a format property that can be set to include the logger name.  Here is a test program to ensure you have set everything correctly.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;


public class SimpleFormatTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //final String format = "%1$ta %1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tl:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL %1$Tp %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%n";
        final String format = "%1$tc %2$s%n%3$s %4$s: %5$s%6$s%n";
        final String key = "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format";
        test(format);
        test(System.getProperty(key, format));
        test(LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(key));
    }

    private static void test(String format) {
        if (format != null) {
            System.out.println("============");
            LogRecord record = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "msg");
            record.setLoggerName("logger.name");
            record.setSourceClassName(SimpleFormatTest.class.getName());
            record.setSourceMethodName("test");
            System.out.println(String.format(format,
                    new java.util.Date(record.getMillis()),
                    record.getSourceClassName(),
                    record.getLoggerName(),
                    record.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),
                    record.getMessage(),
                    record.getThrown() == null ? "" : record.getThrown()));
            System.out.println("============");
        }
    }
}
```

> But I was looking for a solution that would include the prefix in message text. I cannot know what Formatter the user would want to use and he may choose to not log the logger name (in contrast nobody will ever create a Formatter which omits the message text).

Include a `logging.properties` with your application.  You could add a precondition check that disables your code from working at all.  That would force users to set the configuration.

```
 public class NoStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String id = "logger.name";
        LogRecord record = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "msg");
        record.setLoggerName(id);
        File f = File.createTempFile("test", ".tmp");
        try {
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(f.getCanonicalPath(), false);
            try {
                Formatter fmt = fh.getFormatter();
                String r = fmt.format(record);
                if (!r.contains(id)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Formatter must contain logger name.");
                }
            } finally {
                fh.close();
            }
        } finally {
            f.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can create a custom filter to modify the LogRecord message.

```
public class PrefixMessageFilter implements Filter {

    private final String instanceId;
    private final Filter target;

    public PrefixMessageFilter(final String instanceId, final Filter target) {
        this.instanceId = instanceId;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        record.setMessage(instanceId + ' ' + record.getMessage());
        return target == null || target.isLoggable(record);
    }

    //Example code to setup filter.
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(toString());
    {
        logger.setFilter(new PrefixMessageFilter(toString(), logger.getFilter()));
    }
}
```

You just have to modify the logger on first use.

Comment: Some interesting thoughts in your answer. I'm looking into it. However, I must say I disagree with "JUL assumes that you are packaging and setting a logging.properties with your application.".  In my mind the idea is that an operator (i.e. not the developer) can customize this to fit the requirements of the execution environment he is in.

Comment: @peterh Sure I see what you mean.  The point I was trying to convey is that JVM includes a config for its context.  Tomcat includes a config for its context and an web app deployed in Tomcat can include a config for its context.  Each layer in that example would map to an operator role.  So what I meant is that maybe you should provide a starting config for your context and operators could tweak that. That config would include the SimpleFormatter formatted to include the logger name.